# Can't retrieve Resource File data in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, embedded-resource

i'm trying to embed a .bmp file into my application (a simple console app),retrieve the content of this file and then write it to another .bmp on the disk,just to see if I can successfully read my resource.
The project has been created with Visual Studio 2017 :

main.cpp :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "resource.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    HRSRC hresinfo = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1), _T("BITMAP"));
    HGLOBAL hRes = LoadResource(NULL, hresinfo);
    LPVOID data = LockResource(hRes);
    DWORD datasize = SizeofResource(NULL, hresinfo);

    std::cout << datasize;

    ofstream output("test.bmp", std::ios::binary);
    output << data;
    output.close();
    return 0;
}
```

resource.h:

```
//{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}}
// Include file Microsoft Visual C++.
// Used by Resource.rc
//
#define IDB_BITMAP1                     101

// Next default values for new objects
// 
#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE        102
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         40001
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE         1001
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           101
#endif
#endif
```

Resource.rc (interesting part):

```
IDB_BITMAP1             BITMAP                  "bitmap1.bmp"
```

The whole `Resource.rc` : https://pastebin.com/tnRyg64b

However, `cout` returns 0 ,and `test.bmp` is an invalid file. I guess the problem is that I missed something in retrieving my resource's content,but where ?

EDIT: 
Using `output.write(data,datasize)` instead of `output <<` gives me a 0 Ko test.bmp (instead of 1Ko)

Comment: Try to use ofstream::write to write binary data, with count = datasize , instead of operator <<

Comment: @AlexF I tried, with no luck since datasize is 0 -> How is that possible ?

Comment: I would use `HRSRC hresinfo = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1), RT_BITMAP);` and immediately control that `hresinfo` is not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `RT_BITMAP` as suggested earlier. But `data` returned from `LockResource` is not a recognizable bitmap file, it's missing bitmap file header.

You can make your own header as follows:

```
HRSRC hresinfo = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1), RT_BITMAP);
if(hresinfo)
{
    HGLOBAL hRes = LoadResource(NULL, hresinfo);
    LPVOID data = LockResource(hRes);
    DWORD datasize = SizeofResource(NULL, hresinfo);

    ofstream output("test.bmp", std::ios::binary);

    BITMAPFILEHEADER bfh = { 'MB', 54 + datasize, 0, 0, 54 };
    output.write((char*)&bfh, sizeof(bfh));
    output.write((char*)data, datasize);
    output.close();
}
```